# How to pass function as parameter

Tags: c#

Ok, I already passing function as parameter to another function like this:

```
someFunction(..., passFunc);
passFunc(){ MessageBox.Show("Message"); }
private void someFunction(..., Func<int> f) { f(); }
```

This works just fine. I pass "passFunc" to "someFunction" as parameter and then call this parameter("f()"). Then I got messagebox with text "message". Ok.

In later version of program, function "passFunc" is called when I click on specific button's...
Then I wish to get text. I normally do this so: `((Button)sender).Text;`. But in this case I cant do this, because I have no parameters in this "passFunc".

How can I do this? So, that "passFunc" will look like: `passFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Then I'll be able to do this:

```
passFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Text);
}
```

here is code: http://pastie.org/6079188

Comment: Why do you want the text from the button?
`Func<object,EventArgs,string> func = (sender,e) => {return (sender as Control).Text;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass input to a func use this generic type overload:

```
Func<string, int> passFunc
```

EDIT:

You call `passFunc` like this

```
passFunc("some input");
```

EDIT2:

`passFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)` cannot be used with a Func because it probably has a void return type.
You then have to use `Action<object, EventArgs>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you subscribe passFunc to the event handler for that button?
It would look something like this 
`button1.Click += new EventHandler(passFunc)`
and then passFunc would be

```
void passFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Text); 
}
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you want to achieve but it might work.